# Menu Item Showing Image but hiding text. Honeycomb Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, android-screen

I use the below xml file to inflate the menu in my application. This works fine when I test it in my phone. How ever when I test it in my xoom Honeycomb tablet I cannot see the text of the menu Item "menu_addnote" and "menu_addfolder". It shows only the image and the text gets hidden below which is not visible on the screen. How to I specify the drawable size of the menu icons in tablets or phones? Please help me with this. Thank you.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_addnote"
          android:icon="@drawable/add"
          android:title="@string/menu_add" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_addfolder"
          android:icon="@drawable/folder"
          android:title="@string/menu_folder" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
          android:icon="@drawable/sync"
          android:title="@string/menu_sort" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/settings"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_sync"
          android:icon="@drawable/sync"
          android:title="@string/menu_sync" />

</menu>
```